# how to use contact importer module

Tags: 7

I have downloaded and enabled the contact importer module.
Enabled the settings in "Administration » Configuration » Web services » Contact Importer"
I have create a content type called contacts form "contacts_form" with field "field_email".

I have added this field in " Administration » Configuration » Web services » Contact Importer" ->forms integration as form id as "contacts_form_node_form" and filed as "field_email".

when I add email and save then it save as normal page. It does not import contacts.

AM i missing anything (or) any other modifications are needed.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the README? http://drupalcode.org/project/contact_importer.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/README.txt  If yes, and it still doesn't work, you should open a support request in the module's issue queue.  If the module's installation documentation does not accurately describe how to install the module, that is a documentation bug that should be filed on drupal.org.

Comment: @PatrickKenny : yes I have followed the instructions in README.